# Jenkins - how to copy test logs back to artifacts directory for build

Tags: jenkins

New to Jenkins so apologise in advance as I'm sure this answer is out there somewhere.  Just not sure exactly how to search for what I'm after.  I'm struggling a bit with the copyback process in Jenkins.

When I build, I'm running some unit tests that create some log files which I want to be stored as part of the Jenkins build.  I'm running on Windows 10 and everything is running on my laptop (I'm purely trying to learn Jenkins so this is fine for me).

So my test results will always appear in C:\TestLogs\*.log.  I want the results copied to my build directory which is URL:  http://localhost:8080/job/loadrunner_test/1/   absolute:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\loadrunner_test\builds\1

I'm a bit confused with which plugin I should use in my post build step?  Copy Artifact plugin looks as if it's meant to pass data between builds.  For each build, I just want to copy C:\TestLogs*.*  to the current build directory so I can see them when I click on the link for #1 in the Build History.

Many thanks!

Tim

[WindowsDir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCsFE.png)

[Jenkins Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUd3f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy it with additional step.
Select Execute Windows batch command for that step and add this line:

```
xcopy C:\TestLogs C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\jenkins_test\builds\%BUILD_NUMBER% /s /e
```

You can also check configuration for your test if you can set path location.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for such a quick reply!  OK, so that worked a treat, thank you!  However, I can't see the file through Jenkins although it's in the correct directory (I think).  I've edited my post to include some screenshots.

Comment: Try adding a post build action to archive the artifact.  If you are using pipelines there is: `archiveArtifacts`  Some documentation for the pipeline version is here: [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/)

Comment: I guess I should add, you would need to copy the logs into the currently building workspace, instead of the results area, for the archive to work.